# Automatically scan for JPA entities in multiple LIB jar files packaged in WAR file

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, vaadin, war

I have a multi-module Maven web project using JEE 7, JPA 2.1, Wildfly 10.1, and Vaadin 8, which I'm trying to keep modular by having the core application components in the WAR project and importing various other modules, for instance the core module (user/role management, etc.) which includes:

- core-api (service interfaces, JPA entities, etc.)
- core-services (business and persistence EJBs)
- core-ui (Vaadin UI components like @CDIView classes, menu builder ejbs)

So the deployment looks like:

- core-web.war

  - WEB-INF/

    - beans.xml (empty)
    - classes/(single Vaadin UI class, nothing else)
    - lib/

      - persistence.jar (resource lib with just META-INF/persistence.xml)
      - core-api.jar
      - core-services.jar
      - core-ui.jar
      - (Vaadin and various other library jars)

Then as we add other components, we can mix and match for different deployment configurations, e.g. add the accounting module by adding those api, services, and ui jar files, along with the core as shown, to the deployment in a Maven profile.

My problem now is getting JPA to scan all the jar files in the lib folder for entities for the persistence units defined in the persistence.xml.

I don't want to list all the entity classes (or jar files) explicitly because that set will change for different deployments.

Setting exclude-unlisted-classes to false in persistence.xml induces the desired behavior when deployed in an EAR, but Vaadin unfortunately does not play well when deployed inside an EAR. It breaks a lot of its CDI features.

So I'm trying to get this working with a WAR deployment. I've tried including the persistence.xml in the WEB-INF/classes/META-INF folder of the WAR, and in a separate library jar (under /META-INF) in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the WAR, and the only way I've found to get it working is, in the persistence.xml file, to include an empty `<jar-file>` element.

```
<persistence-unit name="my.persistence.unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ApplicationDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <jar-file></jar-file>
</persistence-unit>
```

The persistence.xml validator complains about this in Eclipse, but it works when I deploy to Wildfly; my entities are discovered and retrieved from the database just fine.

But I've only seen this little trick mentioned in one place, and can't find any documentation on it, so I'm hesitant to say "yay we fixed it" when I don't know if we're possibly relying on a bug in Hibernate or something...

Does anyone know if this is a valid fix for the issue? Or if there is some other fix I should try?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a beans xml in each of your modules?

Comment: I did in the base war file and the two EJB jars, not in the plain jar with the API stuff in it, including entity classes. Tried adding beans.xml to the API jar and still getting error "User is not mapped" while User is a JPA-annotated entity class in the API jar file. If I add the empty `<jar-file>` tag to persistence.xml, or add a `<class>` tag with the fully-qualified class name, it works. But I don't want to have to do that for the reasons listed above.

Comment: Maybe you can try `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly#ClassLoadinginWildFly-JBossDeploymentStructureFile

Comment: @MorganP Have you now found a solution to your problem? Also, thanks for the workaround with the empty <jar-file> parameter. Until there is an other way, I will use this approach instead of <class> attributes.

Comment: No, I never did. How sad. We are still using an EAR deployment for the first phase of our project. In a few months we will start on the next phase and I will revisit this. I’ve become a lot more comfortable with Maven since I posted this question, so maybe I’ll find a nice clean way to build the persistence.xml dynamically based on the included jars.